# Related rates, cone-shaped pile of sawdust

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Problem:**

The volume of a cone-shaped pile of sawdust increases by $4.7m^3/\mathrm{min}$. The radius increases 30% faster than the height. How fast does the height increase in the moment that the radius is $5m$ and the height is $7m$? Give the answer in $\mathrm{cm}/\mathrm{min}$ rounded to one decimal place.

**My attempt:**

I don't know if I'm on the right track, but so far, I've thought of this:

Using

$$V = \frac\pi3r^2h$$

and

$$r = r(t)$$

we get, using the chain rule

$$V'(t) = \frac\pi3 \cdot2r(t)h\cdot r'(t)$$

From here, I don't know how to use $h$ or get rid of it. I could certainly use that $r'(t) = 1.3h'(t)$, but it remained a constant during the differentiation, so I'm at a loss.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The differentiation is not right. From $V=(\pi/3)r^2h$, you should get $V'=(\pi/3)(r^2h') +(\pi/2)(2rr'h)$.  For recall that both $r$ and $h$ are functions of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data is $$\frac{dV}{dt} = 4.7, \frac{dr}{dt}=1.3\frac{dh}{dt}, h =7, r = 5 \tag 1 $$you have $$V = \frac13 \pi r^2 h\to \frac{dV}{dt}=\frac13 \pi\left(h2r\, \frac{dr}{dt}+r^2\frac{dh}{dt}\right)\to 4.7= \frac13 \pi\left(70\times 1.3 \frac{dh}{dt}+25\frac{dh}{dt}\right)$$  that is $$\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{3 \times 4.7}{116\pi}m/min $$